# Can a KCPI-3101 be replaced with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm planning to use a KPCI-3101 Keithley with a computer to creat a DAS with a sensor to show the data on computer

can i replace the Card and computer with an Arduino?

Comment: can you elaborate more? what sensor are you trying to use? If you planing to only do trivial computations and sensor readings it may be good.

Comment: Geosig-ve53 is the seismic sensor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Arduino's ADC cannot sample fast enough to sustain 225ksps over 16 channels. That equates to a total of 3.6Msps.  The Arduino can manage something like 120ksps in total.

That's not to say there aren't microcontrollers that can't do that kind of speed - there are.  The PIC32MZ, for instance, can run at 15Msps (although it's somewhat buggy still) and there are many other microcontrollers.

The main bottleneck though is in the communication between the microcontroller and the computer.  Regardless of the sampling speed of an Arduino the serial interface is too slow for high speed sampling. Even at its practical maximum of around 2Mbps it gives you 200000 bytes per second, which with 2 bytes per sample would be 100ksps maximum throughput, not taking into account any protocol overheads.

So that's where having a PCI card is a big advantage. A 32-bit (or even 64-bit on PCI64) 66MHz direct channel to the CPU means you can shift considerably more data. And having the computer perform DMA access means that smooth data transfers without the CPU needing to be involved can be performed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't replace the [KPCI-3101 Keithley's](http://www.testequipmentdepot.com/keithley/multifunction-boards/kpci-3101a.htm) 16 channels of 12 bit 225kS/s with an Arduino.